# Server Side Architecture for smart phone programming

Tags: c#, iphone, wcf

I'm starting to design a smart phone App, the client will run as an App (not browser based App on Iphone, Android and windows mobile. the client will each be programmed in a different language. the thing is i would like to have all of the clients use one framework on the server, my questing is what would be the best design for such a server (HTTP based) i was thinking of either a SOA approach or a REST approach. hoping to learn from other people's trails what is the "Industry standard". last but not list does any one know if WCF has any disadvantage implementing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

SOA and REST are explicitly not mutually exclusive so I think you mean SOAP not SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) ?

REST with JSON as the payload is trivially implemented in Android and iOs, of course you can use any data format you want.

SOAP is still an option and there are plenty of libraries that can do that as well, though any app development that I have been involved in recently has preferred REST.

REST is easier to debug, and much more easily consumed by Javascript, if you ever develop a web client.

Any server side technology can serve up REST, and as you mention WCF you might be tempted to use the more .Net native SOAP. Id advise against that.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean SOAP, why would you advice against SOAP?

Comment: +1 for the answre, though I would disagree that REST is easier to debug.  Ease of debugging depends on the capabilities of the server side and the ability of the consumer to consume JSON.

Comment: Robaticus - Ok, yep, should have steered away from the more contentious arguments. The broader REST vs SOAP discussion probably belongs in other threads.

Comment: user1261437: Theres a lot of well respected advice on why REST is for most average use cases the best option. I think this article is a starting point... http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest